# How to use font awesome in HTML and CSS?

Tags: html, css, font-awesome

I'm trying to use an icon from fontawesome.com but it isn't showing on my web page. My goal is to have a custom play button but instead, I get a rectangle.

I've checked for logical errors like typos or misspelled words.
However, I'm not too sure if the link to the webpage is correct.

---

*This is my index.html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang= "en">

    <head>
        <title>Assignment 4 </title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiz="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <meta name="viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css">


    </head>
__________________________________________________________________________
*This is my style.css *

.buttons button:before{
    content: "\f04b";
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

}

.buttons button.play:before{
    content: "\fo4b";
}

    .buttons button.pause:before{
        content: "\fo4c";

}
```

I expected the output of my code to show the play icon below the embedded video but it shows a square icon instead.

Comment: show your output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `font-family:FontAwesome;` instead of `"Font Awesome 5 Free";`

Answer (score 0):

Replace  `font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";` to  `font-family: FontAwesome;`

```
.buttons button:before{
    content: "\f04b";
     font-family: FontAwesome;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;

}
```